# Dygraphs in collapsed panel not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dygraphs

**I would like to** render a dygraphs graph in a collapsed bootstrap panel. Once the user shows the panel the graph should be visible.

**My problem is** that, when the initially collapsed panel appears, the dygraphs graph inside it is not shown correctly. See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rubinia/eu8qpwng/64/).
My html body looks like this (using bootstrap 3):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <label><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxChanged(this)"/> Show panel 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="panel1" class="panel-body">
          <div id="graphdiv1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="panel2" class="panel-body collapse">
          <div id="graphdiv2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
function checkboxChanged(checkbox){
  if(checkbox.checked){
    document.getElementById('panel1').classList.add("collapse");
    document.getElementById('panel2').classList.remove("collapse");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('panel1').classList.remove("collapse");
    document.getElementById('panel2').classList.add("collapse");
  }
}

g1 = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("graphdiv1"),
  "Date,Temperature\n" +
  "2008-05-07,75\n" +
  "2008-05-08,70\n" +
  "2008-05-09,80\n",
  { title: 'Graph on panel 1' }
);

g2 = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
  "Date,Temperature\n" +
  "2008-05-07,20\n" +
  "2008-05-08,37\n" +
  "2008-05-09,17\n",
  { title: 'Graph on panel 2' }
);
```

**What I get**:
[image]

**What I expect**:
[image]

Note: A curious thing is that, when I resize the output area of the jsfiddle, the graph gets rendered correctly. When I then uncheck the 'show panel 2' checkbox, the first panel graph is rendered incorrectly.

I have tried updating the dygraphs in the end of the checkbox method like this:

```
  g1.updateOptions({});
  g2.updateOptions({});
```

but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

I found **a hack that seems to work**. Any suggestions for a cleaner solution would be much appreciated!

My solution is to place a hidden div, containing `graphdiv2`, at the very end of the document using `visibility:hidden;` (rather than `display:none;`) and then, when the checkbox is checked, to have the two graph divs switch places.

So the html body now looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <label><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxChanged(this)"/> Show panel 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="my_panel" class="panel-body">
          <div id="graphdiv1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="hidden_zone" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <div id="graphdiv2"></div>
</div>
```

And the checkbox onclick function now looks like this:

```
  function checkboxChanged(checkbox){
    graph1_div = document.getElementById("graphdiv1");
    graph2_div = document.getElementById("graphdiv2");
    show_parent = document.getElementById('my_panel');
    hidden_zone = document.getElementById('hidden_zone');
    if(checkbox.checked){
        hidden_zone.appendChild(graph1_div);
        show_parent.appendChild(graph2_div);
    } else {
        hidden_zone.appendChild(graph2_div);
        show_parent.appendChild(graph1_div);
    }
 }
```

Here's the [jsfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/rubinia/zwkp2c3t/59/) to this solution.

Any suggestions for a cleaner solution?